# MySql and ElasticSearch for File Service

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

That's my first question at stackoverflow and I'm hoping to do everything right. This is general question about MySql and/or ElasticSearch.

For example, I am planning a music portal where the users can upload his favorite mp3 files.

**Use Cases:**

1. User has an account and can manage a profile(some personal information  are showing public to all other users)
2. The user can upload mp3 files and tag them with some key words for better search.
3. The files will be saved on disk
4. Other user have the possibility to comment a mp3 file like the youtube comments function
5. The user has the possiblity to Dislike/Like the mp3 file.

My consideration was to use MySql for account, profile and file comments.
For file search by tags I would use the EleasticSearch Database due to of better search functionality.

Now my question:
Is this a good approach? Or should I use only one of them(MySql or EleasticSearch). I'm not sure which database best fits the use cases.
Or may be the file comments better located inside the EleasticSearch.

Comment: Hello @Jayser and welcome to SO ! Thanks for your effort on trying creating a great question. You can even find some more information about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Unfortunately, a question like "which one is better / which one should I use" does not fit very well on stackoverflow, because there is no real answer to it. It will depend on personal preferences, as all 3 options (and also option 4 to 22: use something different) are viable (which might already be all you needed/wanted to hear). It's not even safe to say that using just 1 system instead of 2 would be easier for you, as you in particular might find some things easier to do in mysql and others easier in elastic, that the additional effort to set up 2 systems balances itself out in total.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought such use cases like mine are easy to answer. I am expecting a huge amount of data like comments and tags and I want the fastest way for text search. I want recommendations of similar files to a certain file. Like youtube. For example: I search for files with 3 tags and then I want see all files which matched best and files where only one tag matched and additional files which are not contained any tag but seen by user who searched the file. And of course sorting by date and relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the scenario. If you have no issues in maintaining 2 different databases. You can use MySQL to store account and profile information.

> MySQL schema : User_Info:  userid , username, firstname , lastname,
>   emailId
>
> Mp3_Info:  mp3_id , mp3_title, created_by_user_id, created_date,
>   location_on_disk , mp3_tags, artist , genre
>
> Comments_Info:   comment_id, comment , commented_by_used_id,
>   comment_time

Now you can store the tag_data, mp3_title and corresponding mp3_id in elastic search. Which will support searching an mp3 based on tag or title.  You can also choose to store comments in elasticsearch based on mp3_id on which it was commented and other fields.

This is one of the approaches , you can try further approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have no issues in maintaining because I would use AWS or similar services. I think the best solution is to mix both technologies. I would use elasticsearch for full text search. I think a good way is to store all information, which are necessary for search, aggregation, sorting, in elasticsearch.

Comment: If you want you can store all the mp3 information in elastic only. There by using SQL only for user and profile information.